# build-image failed, No digest found error when tried to create docker image

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, docker

In eclipse terminal, I am trying to create a docker image of Springboot project.

**Command:** `mvn spring-boot:build-image`

In the end I am getting `No digest found error`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.5:build-image (default-cli) on project PROJECT_NAME: Execut
ion default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.5:build-image failed: No digest found -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Could someone help me out here.

Comment: What happens if you build the docker image with the docker build command? What happens if you enable debugging?

Comment: Can you try `mvn spring-boot:build-image -U`?

`-U` is to force maven ignore the local cache

Comment: Did you got any solution? I'm facing the same issue.. @nigel tried with your command also but no luck

Comment: Having the same issue here. Already tried the solution proposed by @Kms but with no success.

Comment: Any update on this  ? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ANEESH T.G , I tried below way which is working fine.

a) Create a Docker file named as **Dockerfile** for SpringBoot project with below detail

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

b) Open Eclipse Terminal for that project,
Select Project-> Right Click -> Show in Local Terminal -> Terminal

c) Ran below command

```
docker build -t springio/gs-spring-boot-docker .
```

And here you go....!!

Please find the screenshot below and [reference document](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/)

[image]

Comment: @ANEESH T.G , Let me know if you faced any issue in that.